# Laravel Eloquent Faceted Search, is this query possible?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, filtering, faceted-search

I have a table `inventory`, which has a one-to-many relationship to a table called `data`. I'm creating a filter application, where the user will be able to filter inventory by color and by material for example. It's important that this information is stored on the `data` table for compatibility purposes.

The `data` table was created to be flexible in terms of scaling the data for inventory. Data table has these columns:

```
inventory_id
key
value
```

What I want to accomplish is if a user is looking for inventory that has material of cotton and a color blue. I want the results to ONLY show inventory that is both.

The issue with my query is that it's showing inventory that has a material of cotton or is the color blue. My query looks like this so far:

```
$values = array_merge($materialValues, $colorValues);

Inventory::query()->whereHas('data', function ($q) {
    return $q->whereIn('key', [
        Enum::MATERIAL->key,
        Enum::COLOR->key
    ])->whereIn('values', $values);
})
```

I've tried something like this for example, which just breaks the query.

```
Inventory::query()->whereHas('data', function ($q) {
    return $q->where('key', Enum::MATERIAL->key)
        ->whereIn('value', $materialValues)
        ->where('key', Enum::COLOR->key)
        ->whereIn('value', $colorValues);
})
```

Also, note that I need to keep this as a builder query since I need to use the paginate method on it.

I feel stuck, is this even possible with eloquent?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```php
Inventory::query()
  ->whereHas('data', function ($q) use ($colorValues) {
      return $q->where('key', Enum::COLOR->key)
          ->whereIn('value', $colorValues);
  })
  ->whereHas('data', function ($q) use ($materialValues) {
      return $q->where('key', Enum::MATERIAL->key)
          ->whereIn('value', $materialValues);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do eloquent query to use subqueries for each condition, so that each condition is applied separately and that only items matching all conditions are returned:

```
Inventory::query()
    ->whereHas('data', function ($q) use ($materialValues) {
        $q->where('key', Enum::MATERIAL->key)
          ->whereIn('value', $materialValues);
    })
    ->whereHas('data', function ($q) use ($colorValues) {
        $q->where('key', Enum::COLOR->key)
          ->whereIn('value', $colorValues);
    })
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I am a little concerned about the performance implications of using whereHas multiple times. But this works great, thank you!